# Update tabs children in jupyter notebook widget

Tags: jquery, python, jupyter-notebook, ipywidgets

I'm trying to update children of a tab widget. So, I first create a simple tab example :

```
from ipywidgets import widgets
from IPython.display import display

lst = ['P0', 'P1', 'P2', 'P3', 'P4']
childs = [widgets.Text(description=name) for name in lst]
tab = widgets.Tab(children=childs)
[tab.set_title(num, name) for num, name in enumerate(lst)]
display(tab)
```

Then, I try to remove the 'P2' tab :

```
child_to_remove = 2
lst.pop(child_to_remove)
tab.children = [i for k, i in  enumerate(tab.children) if k != child_to_remove]
[tab.set_title(num, name) for num, name in enumerate(lst)]
```

If I look at the already displayed Tab, the new titles are : 'P0', 'P1', 'P4' and 'Page 6'. If I run again `display(tab)` the tab is fine. But there is no problem if I remove the last tab `child_to_remove = 4`.

How can I update the first created tab without using `display(tab)` and having the right title for each tab?

Thx !